# Extract last instance of substring from string

Tags: regex, mariadb

Here's my hash:

```
---
0:
  id: 11259
  year: 1997
  status: other
  priority: 
  created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    utc: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
    zone: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeZone
      name: Etc/UTC
    time: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
  updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    utc: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
    zone: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeZone
      name: Etc/UTC
    time: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
1:
  id: 82829
  year: 1931
  status: won
  priority: 
  created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    utc: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
    zone: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeZone
      name: Etc/UTC
    time: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
  updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    utc: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
    zone: !ruby/object:ActiveSupport::TimeZone
      name: Etc/UTC
    time: 2017-01-13 15:02:22.000000000 Z
```

I would like to do one of two things:

(1) Extract both 'id's

```
id: 11259
id: 82829
```

(2) Extract just the final 'id':

```
id: 82829
```

So far I have only be able to extract the *first* ID:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(hash_name, "id: .*?\n")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have a `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function. That function only exists in Oracle and MariaDB.

Comment: MariaDB uses PCRE, so you can use a negative lookahead to look for `id:` that's not followed by another `id:` later in the string. Then it will match the last `id:` in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a MariaDB version that uses PCRE, you can use a negative lookahead to exclude `id:` after the match.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(hash_name, '(?s)id:[^\n]+(?!.*id:)')
```

`(?s)` puts it into `DOTALL` mode so that `.*` matches across newlines. `(?!.*id:)` is a negative lookahead that disallows a match if it's followed by anything that includes `id:`. And `id:[^\n]*` matches `id:` followed by optional anything up to a newline.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/4hc9Fo/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [user defined function](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme) which provide access to perl regex:

```
PREG_CAPTURE(pattern, subject [, capture-group] [, occurence])
```

**EDIT:**

```
PREG_CAPTURE("(?s)id:[^\n]+(?!.*id:)", hash_name)
```

Comment: How would you use this to find the last occurrence of something that repeats an arbitrary number of times?

Comment: "capture a named or numeric parenthesized subexpression from a pcre pattern. Capture from a specific match of the regex or the first match is occurence not specified."

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. How would you create a regexp that can match an arbitrary number of groups, and then how would you know which occurrence number is the last one?

Comment: Instead of just linking to the documentation, you need to post the example code that solve the problem.